# Inserting records with SQLite

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

What is the SQLite statement for "insert"?

I have tried

```
insert into table1 values(field1,field2) values (?,?)
```

but this returns an error in the statement -- how do I do this?

Answer (score 4):

The correct syntax for the insert statement is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_(SQL)):

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, [column2, ... ]) VALUES (value1, [value2, ...])
```

Note that you have put the `VALUES` keyword before the list of column names.